# Use a repeating character as table border

Tags: html, css

I want to create a table with the table border using some repeating character say a `$`. I want the output to be like

```
$$$$$$$$$$$$$
$           $
$    asd    $
$           $
$$$$$$$$$$$$$
```

I thought of using pseudo elements but that won't give the desired result.
Is there a way to achieve this using CSS3?

Comment: Does it have to be a text character, or can it be an image?

Comment: I want to make it configurable at runtime, if possible. I thought of using images though.

Comment: You may be interested in the [`border-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image) property - although [IE browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-image) wouldn't be brilliant... otherwise a few [text-shadows](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/uxdnmc7p/), although not really brilliant, might do the trick.

Comment: not possible if you want actual text with css

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it using svg

```html
<svg width="500" height="500">
    <defs>
    <pattern id="p" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" >
        <text x="0" y="30" font-size="40">$</text>
        </pattern>
    </defs>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="500" height="500" stroke="url(#p)" fill="none" stroke-width="100"/>
```

Comment: Can you do this with text 'asd' in the center?

Comment: @AmmarCSE In svg `text` is aligned using `x` `y` co ordinates so you can align it as needed http://jsfiddle.net/akshay7/pxh3y2fp/

Comment: Not exactly what I need, but this can work with some workarounds.. thanks :)